# Get multiple max variable name

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, get, max

I have 6 variables and each other have integer values, I want to get the variable name which have the greatest value.

The variables are: `$a = 2, $b = 3, $c = 3, $d = 4, $e = 4, $f = 4`

If I use this code:

```
$var = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
arsort($var);
$name = key($var);
```

The variable `$name` will contain only `$d`. The question is, how to get `$d, $e, $f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `array_keys()` with the search argument:

```
$var = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
arsort($var);
$max = reset($var);                      // get the maximum value (first item)
$results = array_keys($var, $max, true); // search for all the maximums and return the keys
```

Or use `max()` without sorting:

```
$var = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$max = max($var);                        // get the maximum value
$results = array_keys($var, $max, true); // search for all the maximums and return the keys
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AbraCadaver ^_^